# JavaScript undefined error on implicit global

Tags: javascript

I had the following code in Javascript, that worked as expected:

```
myFunc = n => {
    for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        c = n[i];
        if (!k) {
            k = initialValue
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the `for` loop to `forEach` as follows:

```
myFunc = n => {
    n.forEach( c => {
        if (!k) {
            k = initialValue
        }
    })
}
```

When I attempt to execute this code, I get the following error message:

```
ReferenceError: k is not defined
```

I was able to fix it by adding a global declaration `var k`, but I am curious why the first set of code is acceptable, but the forEach is not.

*EDIT* To fix the error on line 7 of both examples. And unfixed the second example.

Comment: can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: The first example has too many parenthesis (7th line) to be valid JS.

Comment: Running both examples with the correction made to the 7th line of the first gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: k is not defined`.

Comment: Using variable without defining is a bad practice (furthermore it is prohibited in strict mode), just define your k variable first.

Comment: @GlebkaF Yes, I understand it's bad practice.  I'm typically very verbose in my code and try to follow best practices.  This was part of a code challenge I was participating in to provide a solution with as few characters as possible.  I would never actually use this code in production, but when I encountered the error I was curious about the difference.

Comment: But as TylerY86 said, both versions give that error. You may like to try also a simplified function with just the `if(!k) {}` part and you should get the same error... In non-strict mode you can *set* a previously undeclared global with `k =`, but you get a ReferenceError if you try to use the value of a previously undeclared variable.

Comment: You fixed the first one. You broke the second one. Parenthesis does go at the end of line 7 on the 2nd example.

Answer (score 0):

Must have been a variable escaping a JavaScript sandbox on that site. :)

```js
myFunc = n => {
    for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        c = n[i];
        if (!k) {
            k = initialValue
        }
    }
}

try { myFunc([1]) } catch ( e ) { alert(e) }
```

```js
myFunc = n => {
    n.forEach( c => {
        if (!k) {
            k = initialValue
        }
    })
}

try { myFunc([1]) } catch ( e ) { alert(e) }
```

All you're going to get here is `ReferenceError: k is not defined`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback with the executable snippets.  It must be a quirk of the codefights.com execution environment.  I'm still diving into javascript, and thought I had come across some weird nuance to the language.  I'll know better next time than to post a question just based on one sample.

Comment: Can you post a link to the code on codefights.com? Maybe they have some exposed globals in their javascript sandbox. You should probably report it as a bug. I got rid of the ribbing comment at the top of the answer. You should also mention in your question as to where the problem exists. :)

Comment: Also, if you're golfing at some challenge, figuring out the edges of the environment could come in handy to abuse to create shorter (hackier) code.